# Where are trace files saved in PeopleSoft?

Tags: peoplesoft

In PeopleSoft Enterprise, there is an option to enable [tracing options](http://peoplesoft.wikidot.com/signon-tracing) from the signon screen. (Tracing options are also accessible after logon from `PeopleTools > Utilities > Debug`)

I've enabled tracing for SQL statements for debugging purposes. However, I can't figure out where to find my trace logs on the server once the session is complete.

**Where are trace logs saved in PeopleSoft when trace flags are enabled?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically they are on the Application Server under the directory for your environment.

e.g.

- `<PS_HOME>/appserv/<domain>/LOGS` (quoted from [article](https://talemetry.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/447504-peoplesoft-where-do-i-find-the-peoplesoft-logs))
- `/opt/test/psft/pt/8.53/appserv/prd/LOGS/PSAPPSRV.10742/process_state.txt` (quoted from [blog entry](https://peoplesoftexperts.blogspot.com/2015/04/running-bi-publisher-report-from-online.html))
- `$PS_CFG_HOME/appserv/<DOMAIN>/LOGS` (quoted from [blog entry](http://remotepsadmins.com/2013/06/01/peoplesoft-temp-tmp-directories/))

Comment: It turns out Oracle has an article on this topic: [Locating Trace Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E91187_01/pt855pbr2/eng/pt/tape/task_LocatingTraceFiles-077145.html).